# Is Water the only Liquid of Life?

Tags: earth, biophysics

What makes scientists think that water is better at sustaining life than every other substance?

every organism we know of needs water to survive. In fact, without water, life on Earth would have never begun. but just because we've never discovered an organism that's proven otherwise doesn't mean it's not there.

However, that raises another question: What would life on other worlds need?

Is There Any Plausible Reason Why Aliens Would Evolve To Look Like Us?

Is it (scientifically) proven that water is the only liquid of life?

Comment: We have a statistics of *one* planet; a good guess (maybe really the best one at the moment) would be that extra-terrestrial life evolved similarly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *speculating about life on other planets*, and not physics.

Comment: Extrapolating from a sample size of one is never a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The much more important PHYSICS question is, where can life NOT exist? The answer to that is trivial: it can not exist in thermodynamic equilibrium. Life is defined by perpetual change, thermodynamic equilibrium is the case of no change, at all. Beyond that it is scientifically prudent not to rule out ANY non-equilibrium environment, at all, until sufficient observational data about is is available. If you want to look for life, don't just look at chemistry. Look at nuclear physics and plasma physics, as well.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Kyle Kanos, we only have statistics from one planet. You make the point that there may be undiscovered organisms that can survive without water. Based on our current knowledge, every life form we know of so far has had its components suspended in an aqueous environment. While it is possible there is another form of life that does not require water to survive, just like we have statistics of one planet, we only have one reference point. If we ever see something that is alive that does not require water, it would probably be so drastically different from anything we would have seen before, that I very much doubt we would recognize it as life until it tried saying "Hi". Even then we may not recognize that it is trying to communicate.

> However, that raises another question: What would life on other worlds need?

Honestly since we only have one reference point, there is no way to say what life on another world needs. While we breath a mixture of nitrogen and oxygen, if other life exists, it may very well breath mixtures of halogens. There are too many possibilities to say.

> Is There Any Plausible Reason Why Aliens Would Evolve To Look Like Us?

Not that I know of, I suppose there could be a reason I don't know about though.

> Is it (scientifically) proven that water is the only liquid of life

Again, I don't know. There are many, many, *many* different planets in the universe, and somewhere a completely different form of life may be looking at the stars and wondering if liquid ammonia is the only liquid of life.

I have heard some convincing ideas concerning nitrogen-based life, rather than carbon-based, I'm sure that in the next few years there will be scientific breakthroughs furthering our understanding of alien life. There are billions upon billions of stars, and billions upon billions of planets. Just looking at our solar system, 1 in 8 major planets supports intelligent life. Those are pretty darn good odds for life to exists elsewhere in the universe.

Comment: " I very much doubt we would recognize it as life until it tried saying "Hi"" LOL